# GIT with assembla repository type personal or public?

Tags: git, assembla

I am going to work on a project hosted by assembla / git.
when i do in my visual studio git extension plugin "Git" > "Clone repository",
I need to chose "Repository type" - What is the difference ? Was this defined when i created the repository ? Since i didnt create i only use it, i dont know what to choose.
Thanks

Comment: Can anyone have access to your repository?

Comment: Team Member access: Allow   for team member access, Watcher access: Allow   for watcher access, Non-member access: Allow  for public access.. These are the setting under the project security setting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between public and personal git repository:

Public = Anyone can see this repository. You choose who can commit.

Private (I think you mean this with personal) =  You choose who can see and commit to this repository.

Comment: but this is on my computer so what do you mean anyone can see ? on the project setting on the assembla i can set privacy options.. so why on the computer also they let me this option on clone setting ?

Comment: I don't know assembla, the only thing i could think of is that it asks because you COULD do a fork with it (Which is a new repro)

Comment: Assembla offers both private and public git repositories, both for free and paid.

Comment: but when i clone it, why does the public/private matter ? i work infront of assembla as "main" one to push.